# Excessive Memory Usage in Pandas read_sql compared to DataFrame Size - How to Optimize Memory Consumption?

Tags: sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy, memory-leaks

I'm currently facing a memory consumption issue while using the `pd.read_sql` function in Pandas. Specifically, the memory usage increases significantly during the reading operation, even though the resulting DataFrame itself doesn't seem to account for the observed memory spike.

Code:

```
@profile
def pd_read_mssql_data(
    sql_query: str,
    server: str,
    database: str,
    server_uid: str,
    server_pwd: str,
):
    conn = f"DRIVER={'SQL server'};server={server};database={database};UID={server_uid};PWD={server_pwd}"
    quoted = quote_plus(conn)
    new_con = f"mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={quoted}"
    engine = create_engine(new_con)
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        df = pd.read_sql(sql=sql_text(sql_query), con=conn)

    df_copy = df.copy()  # The memory spike is observed here
    return df
```

Output:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    13     98.2 MiB     98.2 MiB           1   @profile
    14                                         def pd_read_mssql_data(
    15                                             sql_query: str,
    16                                             server: str,
    17                                             database: str,
    18                                             server_uid: str,
    19                                             server_pwd: str,
    20                                         ):
    21     98.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       conn = f"DRIVER={'SQL server'};server={server};database={database};UID={server_uid};PWD={server_pwd}"
    22     98.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       quoted = quote_plus(conn)
    23     98.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       new_con = f"mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={quoted}"
    24     98.9 MiB      0.6 MiB           1       engine = create_engine(new_con)
    25   3733.8 MiB      4.3 MiB           2       with engine.connect() as conn:
    26   3733.8 MiB   3630.6 MiB           1           df = pd.read_sql(sql=sql_text(sql_query), con=conn)
    27
    28   4043.9 MiB    310.1 MiB           1       df_copy = df.copy()
    29
    30   4043.9 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       return df
```

My module version:

```
SQLAlchemy==1.4.46
urllib3==2.0.7
pandas==2.0.2
python version 3.10.9
```

Issue:
After executing the code above, the memory usage increases significantly during the pd.read_sql operation, although the resulting DataFrame (df_copy) doesn't seem to justify the observed memory spike. I expect the memory useage should be around 300 MiB after I call the function to get dataFrame.

What I've tried:
Use `chunksize` and store the data to temp dataframe and delete the temp dataframe after concat it. Finanlly use `gc.collect()`, don't work, it still consume 3000+ Mib memory.

Questions:

1. Why does `pd.read_sql` lead to such a substantial memory increment?
2. How can I optimize memory consumption during SQL data retrieval using Pandas?

I appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to address this memory issue effectively. Thank you!

Comment: Does it also consume that much memory if you install and use `DRIVER={'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'};` or `DRIVER={'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server'};`? It's possible that it's choosing to use the legacy SQL Server Native Client driver, something which is deprecated and hasn't seen any feature updates since SQL Server 2012 days. (Microsoft doesn't even ship it any more as of SQL Server 2022.)

Comment: Aside... SQLAlchemy 1.4 itself is in maintenance mode. Consider upgrading existing applications to use current version from the 2.x series.

Comment: Hi @AlwaysLearning, I have tried SQLAlechmey 2.0.23, problem not solved. I'll try ODBC Driver later.

Comment: Did you read this doc: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html it seems that some parts of the copy aren't "deep" so maybe your data isn't necessarily deeply copied. I would rather think that the real dataframe size can be 3.7gb. What to do to make it smaller, you could probably specify the actual datatypes instead of defaults, and don't use more data than you need, or as you say, batch it. Plus, 4gb is nothing, a raspberry pi has 8gb ram nowadays

Comment: I've tried `copy.deepcopy()` to create a copy dataframe, but it still use around 300 MiB like df.copy() does instead of 4gb . Thus I think it might exist some memory leak?